# Is it possible to create a view in Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access

As the title states - can it be done? I read on a MSDN page that this is not supported, but my assignment request for how. Can, and how can, it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A view is nothing more than a saved SQL SELECT statement. This is what a saved query in Access is (though you can save DML SQL statements, too, of course).

In interactive Access, use the query designer to create any SELECT statement, save it, and you've created a view.

If you want to do it in code, it's pretty easy to find the code for it, using either DDL SQL or DAO.