# How do I Convert MySQL database to Access database

Tags: mysql, ms-access

How can i change this view so it will work in MS accces

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users_with_meta_view AS
 SELECT
      u.id,
      u.user_login AS login,
      u.user_pass AS password,
      u.user_email AS email,
      (select meta_value from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.id and meta_key 
      = 'first_name' limit 1) as first_name,
      (select meta_value from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.id and meta_key 
      = 'last_name' limit 1) as last_name,
      (select meta_value from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.id and meta_key 
  = 'country' limit 1) as country
  FROM wp_users u
```

Comment: What version of access?

Comment: Its access 2013

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a view in Access 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163836/is-it-possible-to-create-a-view-in-access-2010)

Comment: There are no "views" in Access.  Would you like to make it a select query?

Comment: @ashleedawg CREATE VIEW Statement (Microsoft Access SQL) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836312.aspx

Comment: @P.Salmon - How would you execute that?  `The Microsoft Access database engine does not support the use of CREATE VIEW, or any of the DDL statements, with non-Microsoft Access database engine databases.`

Comment: The Select statement, without creating a view is also fine

Comment: @ashleedawg a view is just a query in MS Access. You can execute it, but it doesn't create a view on the server. Instead, it just creates a query. That's what that means.

Comment: your db is MSAccess  or is MySQL  ???

Comment: I have a ODBC connection into MySQL db, and make a link from MS access to this ODBC connection. But the query is made from MS access

Comment: @Erik - ya thanks, that's what I figured.  And you can't create views on outside databases with that command (according to the docs) so seems pretty useless all-around (included for "compatibility" reasons I assume?)

Comment: @ashleedawg It's a way to create queries in Access over an ODBC or an OLEDB connection. I don't recommend using it, since using DAO and querydefs is much more flexible (and ADOX works too if you dislike DAO), but I guess it has a use-case if that's unavailable.

Comment: ...to be run in Access, to create a query in another Access database?  Yeah, there's better ways.  ...I can see how it's existence would throw people off though.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - bit off-topic but do you know if there's a way to setup the [SO API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) so I can query from Access (as a simpler alternative to using [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new))?

Comment: That's indeed a bit off-topic, and not possible as far as I know (unless you're doing really strange things, like writing your own ODBC driver for the SO API that translates SQL to an SO API request and returns the result). You could use the [dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and query off that, but that's old information, and too large to be contained in a single Access database, so you'd have to use a different backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.user_login AS login,
    u.user_pass AS [password],
    u.user_email AS email,
    (select first(meta_value) from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.id and meta_key = 'first_name') As first_name,
    (select first(meta_value) from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.id and meta_key = 'last_name') As last_name,
    (select first(meta_value) from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.id and meta_key = 'country') As country
FROM 
    wp_users As u
```

If troubles with memos, try:

```
    (select first(Left(meta_value, 255)) from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.id and meta_key = 'first_name') As first_name,
```

or:

```
    (select top 1 meta_value from wp_usermeta where user_id = u.id and meta_key = 'first_name') As first_name,
```

Comment: still  got the message Invalid Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object in subquery "first(meta_value)

Comment: If memos, you may try some workarounds. See edited answer, please.